# Flash Virtual Memory Improve

Tags: apache-flex

How can I improve the Flash Virtual Memory since my Flex application has to return huge data. When I read bytes from Byte Array it throws:

> Out Of Memory Exception

Comment: Simple answer is that you can't do it. I believe you can do it on a per-machine basis, but the user on that machine must do it themselves. There is no way to automatically allocate more memory (for security reasons). It'd be best to rework your application so that you are using less data at one time, especially since there is no way of knowing how much memory the end user will actually have.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change defauld VM.

this is how can you do it:

goto: Window -> Preferences

[image: Window->Preferences]

Find Java
Installed JREs - click on it

[image: InstalledJRs]

you should get list of installed JREs
select the one you are using in my case its **Adobe Flash Builder 4.6**

click Edit
then you will get window with Default VM Arguments

[image: Edit JRE]

type there:
**-Xmx1024m**

or any other value of maximum ram value you want to give to virtual machine
it hepled in my case!

Comment: I think he was asking about the runtime VMs for Flash Player.  I don't think these settings will affect that.